# Comparing DataGridView's Cell Value With string

Tags: c#, checkbox

I fill the dvgPeople with the values from database. Insert/Update/Delete/Select commands work fine. The thing I want to do is to fill some components on form with the selected row's values. I can fill the textboxes but I can't handle the checkboxes. And here is the code.

```
if (dgvPeople.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value == "1")
{
    chkGerman.Checked = true;
}
else 
{
    chkGerman.Checked = false;
}
```

And when I debug this strange case occurs:

[image]

Even dgvPeople.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value = 1, it is still false.

Comment: what does ReSharper try to tell you?

Comment: It says "Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison cast the left hand side to type 'string'"

Comment: that's right; see x4rf41's answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trying to check a boolean value against a string object.

This will work:

```
if (dgvPeople.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "1")
{
    chkGerman.Checked = true;
}
else
{
    chkGerman.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: it's not boolean; it's `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Value has the type object

```
Value.ToString().Equals("1")
```

to compare it as a string

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
if (dgvPeople.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString() == "1")
```

Comment: sorry, both your answers are slightly incorrect, always use the .Equals() function of the String type for comparissions